# C++ Hangman Game, how to make "right" letter stick

Tags: c++

I am trying to do a hangman project, but my code isn't working. Whenever I put in the proper letter, the code tells me it is wrong (even though it is right). Not really sure why - the code worked at some point but I changed some things and now I don't know why it doesn't work. So it is probably a simple fix, but I am just not seeing it.

Any help would be very appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int letterFill (char, string, string&);


int main()
{
    string name;
    int maxAttempts = 5;
    int wrongGuesses;
    char letter;

    srand(time(0));

    const string wordList[15] = { "hanukkah", "sparklers", "mistletoe", "menorah", "presents", "reindeer",
        "kwanzaa", "snowman", "eggnog", "celebration", "yuletide", "resolution", "nutcracker", "ornaments", "gingerbread" };

    string correctWord = wordList[rand() % 15];
    string unknown(correctWord.length(),'*');

    cout << correctWord << endl;

    cout << "Welcome to a fun game of winter holiday hangman! What is your name? " << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << name <<", there are some simple things you should know about this game before you start playing!" << endl;
    cout << "You will be trying to guess a randomly selected word by typing in ONE letter at a time " << endl;
    cout << "You will have " << maxAttempts << " tries before losing the game " << endl;
    cout << "And remember, all of the words are winter holiday related. Good luck " << name <<"!" << endl;
    cout << "*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*" <<endl;

    while (wrongGuesses == 0)
    {
        cout << "Guess a letter" << cout;
        cin >> letter;

        if (letterFill(letter, correctWord, unknown)==0)
        {
            cout << endl << "That letter is not in this word! Try again " << endl;
            wrongGuesses = wrongGuesses + 1;
        }

        else
        {
            cout << endl << "You found a letter! Keep up the good work! " << endl;
        }

        if (correctWord==unknown)
        {
            cout << correctWord << endl;
            cout << "Congratulations! You guessed the correct word!" << endl;

        }

    }

    while (wrongGuesses == 1)
    {
        cout << "You have 4 guesses left " << endl;
        cout << "Guess a letter " << cout;
        cin >> letter;

      if (letterFill(letter, correctWord, unknown)==0)
        {
            cout << endl << "That letter is not in this word! Try again " << endl;
            wrongGuesses = wrongGuesses + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << endl << "You found a letter! Keep up the good work! " << endl;
        }

        if (correctWord==unknown)
        {
            cout << correctWord << endl;
            cout << "Congratulations! You guessed the correct word!" << endl;

        }
    }

     while (wrongGuesses == 2)
    {
        cout << "You have 3 guesses left " << endl;
        cout << "Guess a letter " << cout;
        cin >> letter;

      if (letterFill(letter, correctWord, unknown)==0)
        {
            cout << endl << "That letter is not in this word! Try again " << endl;
            wrongGuesses = wrongGuesses + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << endl << "You found a letter! Keep up the good work! " << endl;
        }

        if (correctWord==unknown)
        {
            cout << correctWord << endl;
            cout << "Congratulations! You guessed the correct word!" << endl;

        }
    }

     while (wrongGuesses == 3)
    {
        cout << "You have 2 guesses left " << endl;
        cout << "Guess a letter " << cout;
        cin >> letter;
          if (letterFill(letter, correctWord, unknown)==0)
        {
            cout << endl << "That letter is not in this word! Try again " << endl;
            wrongGuesses = wrongGuesses + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << endl << "You found a letter! Keep up the good work! " << endl;
        }

        if (correctWord==unknown)
        {
            cout << correctWord << endl;
            cout << "Congratulations! You guessed the correct word!" << endl;

        }
    }


     while (wrongGuesses == 4)
    {
        cout << "You have 1 guess left " << endl;
        cout << "Guess a letter " << cout;
        cin >> letter;

          if (letterFill(letter, correctWord, unknown)==0)
        {
            cout << endl << "That letter is not in this word! Try again " << endl;
            wrongGuesses = wrongGuesses + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << endl << "You found a letter! Keep up the good work! " << endl;
        }

        if (correctWord==unknown)
        {
            cout << correctWord << endl;
            cout << "Congratulations! You guessed the correct word!" << endl;

        }
    }

     while (wrongGuesses == 5)
    {
        cout << "Sorry " << name << " you have made 5 wrong guesses!" << endl;
        cout << "Game over. Click any key to exit. Play again soon :) " << endl;
      if (letterFill(letter, correctWord, unknown)==0)
        {
            cout << endl << "That letter is not in this word! Try again " << endl;
            wrongGuesses = wrongGuesses + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << endl << "You found a letter! Keep up the good work! " << endl;
        }

        if (correctWord==unknown)
        {
            cout << correctWord << endl;
            cout << "Congratulations! You guessed the correct word!" << endl;

        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


int letterFill (char guessLetter, string mysteryWord, string& guessWord)
{
    int x;
    int matches=0;
    int lengthWord=mysteryWord.length();
    for (x = 0; x< lengthWord; x++)
    {

        if (guessLetter == mysteryWord[x])
            return 0;

        if (guessLetter == mysteryWord[x])
        {
            guessWord[x] = guessLetter;
            matches++;
        }
    }
    return matches;


}
```

Comment: Check the lines below `if (guessLetter == mysteryWord[x])`. The test is repeated and the second nested section never runs.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't updating the `string guessWord` in your `int letterFill()` function. As soon as you see a letter that matches you return without entering that second `if` statement.

I assume what you want is only to return after fully updating the `guessWord`, based on that what you want to do is iterate through the string, updating `guessWord` as you find matches and after your loop do a check

`if(matches == 0) return 0;
else return matches;`

Comment: Can you explain more (show a fix) about your statements please. Looks like you're on the right track.

Comment: I was working on it, just wanted to throw out where the problem was for her initially.

Comment: Assumption since the name is Meg? If Meg is male then I apologize for the assumption.

Comment: You'll never know. I prefer to use gender agnostic addressing ( πάντα ῥεῖ you know ;-) ). It's a minor point, don't worry.